# Session id in the middle of URL

Tags: testing, jmeter, sessionid

I need to test a application with JMeter, where the session id is part of the URL (in the middle of the URL).
For example (sessionId=`SID-123456`): `www.testServer.de/my/app/SID-123456/search.html`

How can I put the session id in the URL, in a JMeter test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jmeter, the HTTP request field for "PATH" will accept variables.

So, you just need to extract the session ID from the login page (or wherever), store it to a variable, and then have your HTTP request path read "/my/app/${sid}/search.html

Threadgroup would look something like this:

Threadgroup
-- Login Page
---- Regex to extract SID
-- Search Page